# Change focus to new line on tab key press

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A view model has an observable collection of `Line` objects and an `AddLine()` method.

```
public class ViewModel : Notifiable
{
    ObservableCollection<Line> Lines {get; set;}
    public void AddLine() { /*add*/ }
}

public class Line : Notifiable
{
    public LineData LineData {get;set;} 
}
```

`LineData` has fields that I bind to.

A view (XAML) has a `Grid` with an `ItemsControl` bound to the observable collection with a `DataTemplate` for displaying the `Line` object. Other controls exist on the `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Lines}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <ContentControl Content="{Binding LineData}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!-- other controls -->
</Grid>
```

The `LineData` type has a `DataTemplate` in resources with a `Grid` and a couple of `TextBoxes`.

I want the user to be able to tab out of the last `TextBox` in the `LineData` `DataTemplate` into a new `Line`.

So far I have set up an event handler for the preview key down event like so:

```
    private void Amount_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter;
        if (key)
            (DataContext as ViewModel).AddLine();
    }
```

This successfully adds the line, and the new line displays on the screen, but if the user is on the last line in the collection, the focus does not change to the first control in the new line, but to the next control on the `Grid`.

I am not sure why this happening. I guess the XAML is not updating until after the focus changes, or some such thing.

How can I get the focus to change to the newly created line in the `ItemsControl` and not the next control on the `Grid`?

Comment: Handle the KeyDown event of the control. In this event, you can set e.SupressKeyPress = true to make sure the form doesn't see the Tab press

Comment: There is no such property on the KeyEventArgs class. I don't really want to suppress the tab key, I just want the focus to change to the first control on the new line.

Comment: Not PreviewKeyDown, the KeyDown event is different.